# Requiring paper module for NodeJS. Window module missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, paperjs

I am struggling with installing paper module under NodeJS. 
I have tried in many ways, but I am unable to install it, because I have compilation error of the canvas module that is required.

My thought was that I can use the `paper-full.js`, that's used for browsers to require that, instead of the paper module. It went just fine, until I found out that I will need another module named, window, which can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/window but is empty. After `npm install window --save` the `node_modules/window` folder is also empty.

Any ideas how can I get a functioning window module?

Actually, I don't need any graphics for my server, I just need to do some calculations on Voronoi graphs, but the Point 'class' which is used in creating these can be found in the paper module/paper-full.js.

Can I substitute the `window` module with a dummy?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install with `npm install --no-optional` in paperjs folder.

In this way, you can skip the installation of `canvas`.
If you need the canvas module, you can install with [this wiki](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows)

Comment: Okay, now I get no errors at npm install but the canvas module is still missing when I require('paper')

Comment: If you need `canvas module`, it would be necessary to install `canvas module` inside `paperjs module` with [this wiki](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows).